# XSLT Concatenate values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<Order xmnls="">
  <CardCode>VC00001</CardCode>
  <DocEntry>900</DocEntry>
  <DocDueDate>2015-10-10</DocDueDate>
  <Lines>
    <Row>
      <ItemCode>1264276-683</ItemCode> 'Data extract Node'
      <Size>RD</Size>
      <Quantity>12</Quantity>
      <Price>120</Price>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <ItemCode>1264276-685</ItemCode> 'Data extract Node'
      <Size>LG</Size>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Price>100</Price>
    </Row>
  </Lines>
</Order>
```

Hi Here I showed my xml Structure

I  need `XSLT` to parse the data from xml and return Root Node as Below

```
Order-Lines-Row-ItemCode
```

Final output I need is

> ('1264276-683','1264276-685').

```
Please any one help to me out of this issue.
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi Thanks For your concern. I want Xml data parsed by following way  ('A0001','A0002'). It's using to run Query Select Itemcode from oitm where  IN ('A0001','A0002). Here Input data comes from xml files So i want parse and data modified

Comment: Obviously, you did not understand what the previous commenter is trying to say. Please show your current XSLT stylesheet, the one you've managed so far, even if it is not working.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="addressbook"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="ConcatMyXML" match="Lines">
<xsl:variable name="MyConcatVar">
<xsl:for-each select="Rows/ItemCode">
<xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:element name="test">
<xsl:value-of select="$MyConcatVar"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: @Lakshminarayanan Update the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the desired output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="Order/Lines/Row">
     ('<xsl:value-of select="ItemCode" />')
     <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">,</xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output: ('1264276-683') , ('1264276-685')

Comment: Thanks Shudham.... It's possible pass the value for-each  from xml File. It's declare param .   `<xsl:param name="source"  select="Order/Lines/Row/ItemCode"></xsl:param>`.